# Do "True RMS" meters really do RMS if the input is a high frequency signal?

Tags: measurement, multimeter, rms

I'd like to measure the average of a signal which is mostly zero (less than a few nanovolts as best as I can tell) but may have occasional nonzero "blips" of maybe 20-100 nanoseconds (maybe 1V tall).  I can catch them on a scope, but it is kind of hard to figure out how common they are and what their total area under curve is.

Would a "True RMS" meter produce meaningful input from this kind of signal? (RMS current/voltage/power, any is fine)  If yes, how does that work?

Comment: This is what an integrating scope is for.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams:  Great!  I've never seen (or heard of) a scope like that, and I couldn't find one on google. Can you give an example?

Comment: Depends on the bandwidth of the meter, which should normally be specified in the manual. For example, my True-RMS meter is spec'd over the following ranges: 40Hz~1kHz,  1kHz~10kHz and 10kHz~20kHz basically saying that it cannot be used for signals > 20kHz. Other meters have different bandwidths of course.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Cool, thanks!  Would this keep updating the integral if running in continuous capture mode? Or does it just calculate the integral of the signal it has captured once?

Comment: It will keep integrating as long as you don't reset it.

Comment: I think I misremembered the scope :P https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dh0xYu8YvaE

Comment: You can anlyticaly solve this. First you make FFT transform, you look the bandwidth of meter, cut all HF signals above, do the inverse FFT and you compute RMS of signal. That's what the meter will measure, probably.

Comment: It might be easier and more beneficial to build an integrator using a fast op-amp. Trying to ascertain the RMS value sounds meaningless from what you have described. Maybe some background on the problem would help?

Comment: Anything you can make or buy for a reasonable price is going to have an enormous offset relative to a 'few nanovolts'. Maybe you can just count the pulses during a given period and calculate the voltage.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - Frankly, I don't think the poster really means nanovolts. Millivolts maybe. His pulses are about a volt high, and if he needs 9 orders of magnitude dynamic range on an integrator good for 100 nsec pulses - well, I sure wouldn't want to try it. He might try channeling the ghost of Jim Williams. And if he's confusing millivolts and nanovolts, he may have some difficulties there.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Six orders of magnitude does make a difference..